# Load CSV file to MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to load csv file into MySQL database using below command. But getting error for date column as below. Can someone help me with this?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/ES_USER_ROLES.csv'
INTO TABLE ES_USER_ROLES
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(ID,EMP_ID,FULL_NAME,ROLE_ID,STATUS,CREATED_BY,CREATION_DATE,LAST_UPDATED_BY,LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
SET CREATION_DATE = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@CREATION_DATE,'%d-%b-%y'),'%Y-%m-%d');
```

Snippet from CSV file :

```
root@ctrls-ux-pacman-uat-sql:~# head -2 /var/lib/mysql-files/ES_USER_ROLES.csv
25153,"108918","",68,,118299,09-JUN-21,118299,09-JUN-21
3256,"200363","",69,,517209,16-AUG-18,517209,16-AUG-18
```

MySQL error:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/ES_USER_ROLES.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE ES_USER_ROLES
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> (ID,EMP_ID,FULL_NAME,ROLE_ID,STATUS,CREATED_BY,CREATION_DATE,LAST_UPDATED_BY,LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
    -> SET CREATION_DATE = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@CREATION_DATE,'%d-%b-%y'),'%Y-%m-%d');
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '09-JUN-21' for column 'CREATION_DATE' at row 1

mysql> desc ES_USER_ROLES;
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID               | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| EMP_ID           | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FULL_NAME        | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ROLE_ID          | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| STATUS           | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CREATED_BY       | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CREATION_DATE    | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LAST_UPDATED_BY  | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LAST_UPDATE_DATE | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading into @creation_date change

(ID,EMP_ID,FULL_NAME,ROLE_ID,STATUS,CREATED_BY,CREATION_DATE,LAST_UPDATED_BY,LAST_UPDATE_DATE)

to

(ID,EMP_ID,FULL_NAME,ROLE_ID,STATUS,CREATED_BY,@CREATION_DATE,LAST_UPDATED_BY,LAST_UPDATE_DATE)

and reread the section Input Preprocessing in the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: Now I am getting error as below. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/ES_USER_ROLES.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE ES_USER_ROLES
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 LINES
    -> (ID,EMP_ID,FULL_NAME,ROLE_ID,STATUS,CREATED_BY,@CREATION_DATE,LAST_UPDATED_BY,@LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
    -> SET CREATION_DATE = STR_TO_DATE(@CREATION_DATE,'%d-%b-%y'),LAST_UPDATE_DATE=STR_TO_DATE(@LAST_UPDATE_DATE,'%d-%b-%y');
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'STATUS' at row 1

Comment: Please add table definition as text to the question.